# How to replace strings that are similar

Tags: python, string, replace

I am creating some code that will replace spaces.
I want a double space to turn into a single space and a single space to become nothing.

Example:

```
string = "t e s t  t e s t"
string = string.replace('  ', ' ').replace(' ', '')
print (string)
```

The output is "testest" because it replaces all the spaces.
How can I make the output "test test"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression approach is doubtless possible, but for a quick solution, first split on the double space, then rejoin on a single space after using a comprehension to remove the single spaces in each of the elements in the split:

```
>>> string = "t e s t  t e s t"
>>> ' '.join(word.replace(' ', '') for word in string.split('  '))
'test test'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another idea:

```
>>> s = 't e s t  t e s t'
>>> s.replace(' ', '  ').replace('   ', '').replace('  ', '')
'test test'
```

Seems to be faster:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: s.replace(' ', '  ').replace('   ', '').replace('  ', ''))
2.7822862677683133
>>> timeit(lambda: ' '.join(w.replace(' ','') for w in s.split('  ')))
7.702567737466012
```

And regex (at least this one) is shorter but a lot slower:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: re.sub(' ( ?)', r'\1', s))
37.2261058654488
```

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned about the speed in any case, but I liked the idea of doubling the spaces first. (I'm torn whether I think it's clearer than the splitting and rejoining approach, but it's at least worth knowing about.) For some reason, when you edited your answer to add the regex, the spacing got screwed up, which ruins your primary answer.

Comment: @JohnY Yeah, I don't care much about the speed, either, I was just a little curious so I did the test and shared it. What do you mean the spacing got screwed up? I did change the spaces (replace three with zero instead of replacing four with one), but it should still work.

Comment: I must have misread it. Still, I found it easier to see quickly what you were doing when it was 4 spaces to 1. Also, this changes the effect somewhat, if the input starts with three adjacent spaces. Of course, OP never said explicitly what should happen in that case, and it probably doesn't matter, but my intuition is that a triple space should be treated more like "a double space followed by a single space" (becoming single) rather than "three single spaces" (becoming empty).

Comment: @JohnY In my opinion, if more than two consecutive spaces were possible, then the question would have talked about that. Also, my original version would've treated three spaces "correctly", but not four (which it deletes, whereas you'd probably say they should become two). So if more than two spaces were possible, then it's probably doomed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I like this regex solution because you can easily read what's going on:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "t e s t  t e s t"
>>> re.sub(' {1,2}', lambda m: '' if m.group() == ' ' else ' ', string)
'test test'
```

We search for one or two spaces, and substitute one space with the empty string but two spaces with a single space.